# Lightning getError() returns undefined

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, error

I have a server-side method which just inserts a record which is fairly simple and has been working without issue for some time now.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String insertRFQL(inscor__RFQ_Line__c objRFQL) {
    if (!Schema.sObjectType.inscor__RFQ_Line__c.isCreateable()) {
        throw new System.NoAccessException();
    }

    objRFQL.Id = null;
    insert objRFQL;
    return objRFQL.Id;
}
```

A couple of times, a customer has submitted a support ticket with this error
[image]

I assume that this error pops up because we try to loop through the array returned by getError() but it is not actually returning an array of errors but instead returns undefined. I have already modified the code to check to make sure that the array is actually an array before looping through them and if it is undefined or null then just return an Unknown Error.

My question is, why would a server side action return with a state == ERROR but not have a value when calling getError(). The fact that this action works almost every time and I have never been able to reproduced it makes me think that this is an internal salesforce error but I have not been able to find any information when searching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html), you should always throw an AuraHandledException (or a custom exception that extends this one). Why? I don't know, but that's what we're told to do. At minimum, it just means you need to:

```
try {
    if (!Schema.sObjectType.inscor__Purchase_Order_Line__c.isCreateable()) {
        throw new System.NoAccessException();
    }

    objRFQL.Id = null;
    insert objRFQL;
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
}    
return objRFQL.Id;
```

This should always work for anything short of governor limit exceptions and the like.

Comment: Do you know why a server-side action would fail sometimes and work other times with the same input?

Comment: @ZackWalton No, you'd have to talk to someone that knows more about the framework. The only thing I know for certain is that we're supposed to use AuraHandledException. It's all over the documentation.

Comment: A quirk from AuraHandledExceptions is that you need to e.setMessage the error manually if you want the debugger to make sense of it, otherwise it gets mangled and you don't see the lower level error message in your logs.